# How do I access the current post object within a block theme template or pattern?

Tags: theme-development, post-meta, query-posts, full-site-editing

How should I be able to query things like specific metadata or any other thing from the post object? Apparently I don't have access to basic functions like `get_the_ID()` or similar functions inside block theme patterns (where I at least can use php).